# JavaScript function fails if user changes text in textarea

Tags: javascript

I have a button that inserts a html tag with the date into a textarea that is populated from a database query. If the button is pressed without changing the text it works fine but if the user were to change the text in the textarea and then press the button, it does not insert the code. I can't understand why. Here is the function that triggers when the button is pressed:

```
function addtxt(input) {
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var obj=document.getElementById(input);
today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
var txt=document.createTextNode(" <font color=\"#FF0000\">UPDATE " +today+ ": </font>");
obj.appendChild(txt);
```

And the button that calls this function:

```
<input onclick="addtxt('textarea1')" type="button" value="Insert Update Text" id="button1">
```

Thank you for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the last line in your code from

```
obj.appendChild(txt);
```

to

```
obj.value = obj.value + txt.data;
```

it should work. Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LyQeN/13/)

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the button before input something in the textarea, the `txt` text node which you created will appended to that textarea element, and the `today` will be replaced with the real date, but the html tags will remain unchanged. Why? I think maybe the textarea is aimed to display only text. if you click the button after you input something, the `addtxt` funcion wont work even if you clear the textarea. Why? well, if you use Chrome's developer tool to look the source code, you will find why.

Here is an online demo: http://jsbin.com/litov/1/

First input something in that textarea, then clear it. after that, the `addtxt` function wont work. you just click it.

Second, open the Chrome's developer tool, inspect the textarea element, you will find the text node actually appended.

Comment: the reason I am inserting the HTML tags is because after the edit it gets saved to the database. When it reads back out into an html page it needs the formatting to show properly. It does seem to work fine now. Thanks!